# SQL Server 2005 - Calculate Average Open and Click Rate of Subscribers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I want to calculate the average open and click rate of each email contact, since Feb 1 to now.

I know I could build out a query to populate the number of email sends per contact, and then another table for number of unique opens and then divide those numbers, but is there an easier way?

My final table will have subscriberkey, average open rate, average click rate.

I am using Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Salesforce CRM and Marketing Cloud Connect? If so, You could use Salesforce data extensions, and pass click and open data at the individual level or aggregate level.

This way you could create easy-to-use reporting in Salesforce without having to write queries.